# Sorting by another related model attributes - Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models related with each other as below

```
class Weed < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_transactions, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

This **weed** model has an attribute name **county**

and related model:

```
class UserTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :weed
end
```

Now I want to fetch records from **UserTransaction** model on the basis of sort by **county** in weed model and find by county too.

Please suggest me, How can I get correct result with in minimum complexity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserTransaction.joins(:weed).order('weeds.county DESC')
UserTransaction.joins(:weed).where(weeds: { county: 'something' }).order('weeds.county DESC')
```

Comment: UserTransactions will throws an error of "NameError: uninitialized constant UserTransactions" so you should use UserTransaction instead of UserTransactions.

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput it's a typo

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by **county** you can do like this:

```
UserTransaction.joins(:weed).order("weeds.county DESC")
```

or if you want to find by **county** then use :

```
UserTransaction.joins(:weed).where("weeds.county"=> "xyz")
```